# Multiple Carousel For Multiple Cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

```js
let slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  let i;
  let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 1000); // Change image every 1 seconds
}
```

```css
.project-card {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}

.project-screenshots {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.project-screenshots li img {
  width: 100%;
}

.fade {
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    scale: 1.2;
  }
  to {
    scale: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="project-card">
  <ul class="project-screenshots" id="slider">
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GgceYGYr2pk/YPCQp8loxqI/AAAAAAAACXU/Y795AFD-cN8PMV0V2__z2n1B3KFagE8qgCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/1.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pl0VR_xS5Cw/YPCQp1scezI/AAAAAAAACXc/oB9xc6k8RuY5rPksMSy01f3iUn8zSIFzwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/2.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dt6CL2fiBq0/YPCQp0zmK6I/AAAAAAAACXY/0PevDL7pvx87mefb4oCnO613N1UitdicQCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/3.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T_V-s57aVDo/YPCQrWayswI/AAAAAAAACXg/h1ifJGnBuXovvBdGDNvmhg-DXIVK4Xw9QCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/4.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TNT1a5M1v3o/YPCQrWmn_fI/AAAAAAAACXk/p8nx_OB2R6Aw172WIv5vuB8jF-qWDsHlwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/5.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="project-card">
  <ul class="project-screenshots">
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GgceYGYr2pk/YPCQp8loxqI/AAAAAAAACXU/Y795AFD-cN8PMV0V2__z2n1B3KFagE8qgCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/1.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pl0VR_xS5Cw/YPCQp1scezI/AAAAAAAACXc/oB9xc6k8RuY5rPksMSy01f3iUn8zSIFzwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/2.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dt6CL2fiBq0/YPCQp0zmK6I/AAAAAAAACXY/0PevDL7pvx87mefb4oCnO613N1UitdicQCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/3.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T_V-s57aVDo/YPCQrWayswI/AAAAAAAACXg/h1ifJGnBuXovvBdGDNvmhg-DXIVK4Xw9QCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/4.jpg">
    </li>
    <li class="slides fade"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TNT1a5M1v3o/YPCQrWmn_fI/AAAAAAAACXk/p8nx_OB2R6Aw172WIv5vuB8jF-qWDsHlwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/5.jpg">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this code, I have two cards. Each one should have its own carousel. But in the output I'm getting the carousel alternatively. I know its because I have used the same class name for the slides and used the same JavaScript code. I can change them and write the same JavaScript code multiples times. But I want a minimal solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- target all the parent elements
- use a better class naming convention
- use `setInterval` to toggle a class on your items LI elements like `.is-active`
- set in CSS the desired `is-active` styles
- set a (if needed) mouseenter and mouseleave (or with pointer events) Events to pause the interval if the mouse is over your slider

```js
const sliderify = (elSlider) => {
  const elsItems = elSlider.children;
  let itv = null;
  let i = 0;
  
  const anim = () => {
    elsItems[i].classList.remove("is-active");
    i += 1;
    i %= elsItems.length;
    elsItems[i].classList.add("is-active");
  };
  
  const play = () => itv = setInterval(anim, 3000);
  const stop = () => clearInterval(itv);
  
  elSlider.addEventListener("pointerenter", stop);
  elSlider.addEventListener("pointerleave", play);
  
  // Init:
  anim(); // Show first items
  play(); // Loop!
  
};

document.querySelectorAll(".slider").forEach(sliderify);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100px; /* as you need */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-item {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  scale: 1.2;
  transition: 0.4s;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none; 
}

.slider-item.is-active {
  opacity: 1;
  scale: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.slider-item img {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slider">
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T_V-s57aVDo/YPCQrWayswI/AAAAAAAACXg/h1ifJGnBuXovvBdGDNvmhg-DXIVK4Xw9QCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/4.jpg">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TNT1a5M1v3o/YPCQrWmn_fI/AAAAAAAACXk/p8nx_OB2R6Aw172WIv5vuB8jF-qWDsHlwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/5.jpg">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GgceYGYr2pk/YPCQp8loxqI/AAAAAAAACXU/Y795AFD-cN8PMV0V2__z2n1B3KFagE8qgCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/1.jpg">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pl0VR_xS5Cw/YPCQp1scezI/AAAAAAAACXc/oB9xc6k8RuY5rPksMSy01f3iUn8zSIFzwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/2.jpg">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dt6CL2fiBq0/YPCQp0zmK6I/AAAAAAAACXY/0PevDL7pvx87mefb4oCnO613N1UitdicQCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/3.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="slider">
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-GgceYGYr2pk/YPCQp8loxqI/AAAAAAAACXU/Y795AFD-cN8PMV0V2__z2n1B3KFagE8qgCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/1.jpg">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pl0VR_xS5Cw/YPCQp1scezI/AAAAAAAACXc/oB9xc6k8RuY5rPksMSy01f3iUn8zSIFzwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/2.jpg">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-dt6CL2fiBq0/YPCQp0zmK6I/AAAAAAAACXY/0PevDL7pvx87mefb4oCnO613N1UitdicQCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/3.jpg">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-T_V-s57aVDo/YPCQrWayswI/AAAAAAAACXg/h1ifJGnBuXovvBdGDNvmhg-DXIVK4Xw9QCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/4.jpg">
  </li>
  <li class="slider-item"><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-TNT1a5M1v3o/YPCQrWmn_fI/AAAAAAAACXk/p8nx_OB2R6Aw172WIv5vuB8jF-qWDsHlwCNcBGAsYHQ/s16000/5.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The pausing feature is important for UX. Nice and simple implementation!